# EF5, Model-First, Generate Migration T-SQL.xaml seems to be not installed in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I am trying to get Model First DBGen working especially when one changes the model and one wishes to retain any data in the DB. VS2012 complains about a missing , "Generate Migration T-SQL.xaml" in "Entity Framework Tools \DBGen" where only "TablePerTypeStrategy.xaml" exists.

I did try to copy in this file from the VS2010 install, but this did not work.

I am a bit puzzled why I am getting an incomplete EF5 install since I have just installed VS2012 as of yesterday.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks,

Ed

P.S I did try this in VS2010, got a lot further, but when I executed the edmx.sql I got

"Msg 50000, Level 16, State 127, Line 6
Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Exiting."

Comment: What do you expect to happen? EF model first doesn't offer incremental database development.

Comment: Hi Ladislav, Well I can now do this with VS2010/EF5. Therefore if I add a column to my model entity, then I can then get that column added to the DB via the "Migration T-SQL" option as long as I remove the error "Rows found" in the script. No problems. The issue here is that all the DBGen scripts that are in the VS2010 DBGen folder as part of the PowerPack install are not in the VS2012 DBGen folder apart from TPT which VS2010 had prior to the Powerpack install.

Comment: The problem is that Database Generation Power Pack is not updated to support VS 2012. And according to its page on Visual Studio Gallery there will be no more updates.

Comment: Ahh..... That explains alot. So do we have a loss in functionality in VS2012 in this respect, or is this functionality elsewhere? Because of this I have gone back to using VS2010. Cheers.

Comment: Just found this, see: http://astondean.com/entity-framework-the-future-of-model-first-in-a-world-of-magic-unicorns. Rowan Miller is a key EF man I believe, so his comment on this blog seems very reassuring. Basically still supported, and coming ASAP. Very interesting.

Comment: That just points to general expectations to support EF migrations with Model first - it would be great but it is not supported yet.